# No module named rest_framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, pip

i've seen a lot of people having trouble with this here, and i always see them saying other to use pip3 or just pip to install it.

But in my case i've uninstalled it and installed id multiple times both using pip or pip3 and none of them seem to work.

I've added 'rest_framework' to my settings as well and still doesn't seem to work.
Help me out please

```
EDIT
Here is my settings

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'agenda.apps.AgendaConfig',
    'rest_framework',

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

> Collecting djangorestframework   Downloading
>   djangorestframework-3.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 506kB/s  Installing collected packages: djangorestframework Successfully installed
>   djangorestframework-3.7.3

Still not working

EDIT 2

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> line 226, in wrapper
>     fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> line 121, in inner_run
>     self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 374, in check
>     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 361, in _run_checks
>     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
> line 81, in run_checks
>     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
> line 14, in check_url_config
>     return check_resolver(resolver)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
> line 24, in check_resolver
>     for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
> line 35, in __get__
>     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
> line 313, in url_patterns
>     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
> line 35, in __get__
>     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
> line 306, in urlconf_module
>     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>     __import__(name)   File "/home/cyro/PycharmProjects/MyClinic/MyClinic/urls.py", line 20, in
> <module>
>     url(r'^agenda/', include('agenda.urls')),   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py",
> line 50, in include
>     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>     __import__(name)   File "/home/cyro/PycharmProjects/MyClinic/agenda/urls.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>     from . import views   File "/home/cyro/PycharmProjects/MyClinic/agenda/views.py", line 8, in
> <module>
>     import rest_framework ImportError: No module named rest_framework
```

Comment: Post the code you have, are you using virtualenv?

Comment: if you are using virtualenv, activate the environment using the `source <virtualEnvName>/bin/activate`

Comment: If you are using a Virtual Environment (VE), it will have its own tool(s) for installing modules that you can see in the VE.  You may be using a VE and not even be aware of it, depending on what you've installed.

Comment: And did you try `pip install djangorestframework`?  I only ask because it's one of those packages where the `pip install` <name> does not match the `import` <name>.

Comment: @guillermochamorro i'm not using virtualenv

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'agenda.apps.AgendaConfig',
    'rest_framework',

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}

Comment: @Gary02127 Yes i've tried it

Comment: Show the stack trace where the error occurs.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Okiedokie

Comment: I see the dist package says python 2.7 but it always says that even if i install it with pip3

Comment: You mention both `pip` and `pip3`, and you tagged your question `python-3.x`; you are, however, using Python 2.7, so `pip3` should be out of the question. Possibly, `pip` also is set to use Python 3. You need to try and use `pip2`. Also, your stack trace shows `/usr/local/lib` instead of `/usr/lib`, suggesting you use a Python installation that is not the system default. Yet `pip` may point to e.g. `/usr/bin/pip`, which would the system default.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are using Python 2 or 3, and which one you'd like to use.

Comment: I'm using python 3.5

Comment: @Evert also i want to keep using 3.5, the current python using on my linux is 2.7 but the project is using a 3.5

Comment: Try with `python3.5 -m pip install djangorestframework` (prepended with `sudo` if necessary).

Answer (score 5):

Try using `sudo pip install djangorestframework`, I've seen other SO questions and it seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add `rest_framework` just before `agenda.apps.AgendaConfig` in the installed apps in settings.py file. It seems that `agenda` app using some rest_framework libraries before it is initialized.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'agenda.apps.AgendaConfig',


]
```

This answer assumes that you have successfully installed rest_framework and activated virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the old issue.
But may be someone will find this solution helpful.
When you are using

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

It will install this package in your computer's local user python folder and django is unable to read this package so we get the

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'

Instead we will have to install this package inside our development environment.

So use this command instead

```
python -m pip install djangorestframework
```

Hope this helps.